# Fortran subroutine NaN issue when multiple outputs are assigned to the same variable in the main program

Tags: memory, gfortran, subroutine

I tend to use temporary variables to "ignore" some subroutine outputs in Fortran. Since Fortran doesn't have a command like tilde (~) in Matlab, I have to get the outputs fron the subroutine but I assign them to the same temporary variable with the right size. It has been my preference to make things look cleaner, no practical purposes.

So far for years I had no problems with it; today, I am having issues. It turns out, when I assign the outputs to the same variable (temp1), C_DU is a matrix with all zero although it shouldn't be so.

My question is, is it bad practive to assign multiple subroutine outputs to the same variable in the main code? Why is everything suddenly becoming zero when I do that? I appreciate any help.

Below is a minimum working example:

```
program example
    implicit none

    real(kind=8) :: temp1(3,3)
    real(kind=8) :: temp2(3,3)
    real(kind=8) :: temp3(3,3)
    real(kind=8) :: temp4(3,3)
    real(kind=8) :: temp5(3,3)
    real(kind=8) :: r_PN_U(3)

    call r_calc(4.2d0, &
        0d0, 0d0, &
        0d0, 0d0, &
        0d0, 0d0, &
        0d0,      &
        0d0, 0d0, &
        0d0,      &
        0d0, 0d0, &
        0d0, 0d0, &
        r_PN_U, &
        temp1, temp1, temp1, temp1, temp1)

    call r_calc(4.2d0, &
        0d0, 0d0, &
        0d0, 0d0, &
        0d0, 0d0, &
        0d0,      &
        0d0, 0d0, &
        0d0,      &
        0d0, 0d0, &
        0d0, 0d0, &
        r_PN_U, &
        temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5)
end program example

subroutine r_calc(rin, &
    e,     ed,     &
    f,     fd,     &
    v,     vd,     &
    vp,            &
    w,     wd,     &
    wp,            &
    theta, thetad, &
    y_pos, z_pos, &
    r_PN_U, &
    C_DU_theta, C_DU_beta, C_DU_zeta, C_DU, C_UD)
    implicit none

    real(kind=8), intent(in) :: rin

    real(kind=8), intent(in) :: e,     ed
    real(kind=8), intent(in) :: f,     fd
    real(kind=8), intent(in) :: v,     vd
    real(kind=8), intent(in) :: vp
    real(kind=8), intent(in) :: w,     wd
    real(kind=8), intent(in) :: wp
    real(kind=8), intent(in) :: theta, thetad

    real(kind=8), intent(in) :: y_pos, z_pos

    real(kind=8), intent(out) :: r_PN_U(3)

    real(kind=8), intent(out) :: C_DU_theta(3,3)
    real(kind=8), intent(out) :: C_DU_beta (3,3)
    real(kind=8), intent(out) :: C_DU_zeta (3,3)
    real(kind=8), intent(out) :: C_DU      (3,3)
    real(kind=8), intent(out) :: C_UD      (3,3)

    real(kind=8) :: beta, zeta

    beta  = -atan(wp) ! [rad], flap down angle
    zeta  =  atan(vp) ! [rad], lead angle

    call angle2dcm(theta, beta, zeta, C_DU_theta, C_DU_beta, C_DU_zeta, C_DU)

    print *, C_DU ! gives all zero in the first call, correct values in the second call

    C_UD = transpose(C_DU)

    r_PN_U = [rin+e+f, v, w] + matmul(C_UD, [0d0, y_pos, z_pos])

end subroutine r_calc

subroutine angle2dcm(phi, theta, psi, C_phi, C_theta, C_psi, C_out)
    implicit none

    ! Calculates the direction cosine matrix in psi - theta - phi (3 - 2 - 1) order
    ! Difference from "angle2dcm" subroutine is the extra outputs

    real(kind=8), intent(in)  :: phi, theta, psi

    real(kind=8), intent(out) :: C_psi(3,3), C_theta(3,3), C_phi(3,3), C_out(3,3)

    C_phi(1,1:3) = [1d0,       0d0,      0d0]
    C_phi(2,1:3) = [0d0,  cos(phi), sin(phi)]
    C_phi(3,1:3) = [0d0, -sin(phi), cos(phi)]

    C_theta(1,1:3) = [cos(theta), 0d0, -sin(theta)]
    C_theta(2,1:3) = [       0d0, 1d0,         0d0]
    C_theta(3,1:3) = [sin(theta), 0d0,  cos(theta)]

    C_psi(1,1:3) = [ cos(psi),  sin(psi), 0d0]
    C_psi(2,1:3) = [-sin(psi),  cos(psi), 0d0]
    C_psi(3,1:3) = [      0d0,       0d0, 1d0]

    C_out = matmul(C_phi, matmul(C_theta,C_psi)) ! psi - theta - phi (3 - 2 - 1) order

end subroutine angle2dcm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is illegal to assign the same variable as multiple actual arguments that may be changed in the subroutine. It is called aliasing and is forbidden in Fortran. Because your code is not standard conforming, the output can be anything.

Use different variables for each argument.

Comment: I had no idea. Thank you for your answer. Is that same situation valid for the inputs of the subroutine? Can I use the same variable in the main program for two or more different inputs to the subroutine?

Comment: You can, but you may not change such input argument. Further control can be done using target and pointer.